# printing an image from a popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I am trying to showing one image in bootstrap modal, also that pop-up window have one print button, so i need to take the print of that image, which showing in pop-up window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
   function code(){    
     $("#qbody").html("<p align='center'><img 
     src='http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?
     cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=code&chld=H|0'/></p>");  
   }  
</script>  
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-body" id="qbody">
   <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary pull-left'
   onClick='window.print();'>Save</a>"
  </div> 
</div>
```

But here i click the save button that whole page will take as print, not taking that pop-up window image. How is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom css for print media

```
@media print{
   body{
     visibility: hidden;
   }
  .to-print{
     visibility: visible;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
   }
}
```

Now add class `.to-print` to div you want to print, in your case to `img` tag.

Check it out at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarowar/3Cxky/) *(it is not using modal window, loaded directly)*

Comment: here ,if the top and left is 0, then got the half of image, just i changed into some like 20,20
have any suggestions?

Comment: top and left 0 means that printed content goes to top left corner of the page. it is not responsible for half image. some thing else like div size *(if you are printing with parent div, not only `img`)* or something else.

Comment: when i am trying to print via google chrome, that will shows one blank page. But it ok with firefox? what that happens?

Comment: can u give any link to the page? or jsfiddle?

Comment: i think the problem will happen, when i am using the modal window. Have any changes?

Comment: got it from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638424/how-to-create-a-print-modal-using-javascript-jquery-etc

Comment: i have used like this
$(function() {
  $('#printme').click(function(){
    var contents = $('#qr-code-body').html();
    var frame = $('#printframe')[0].contentWindow.document;

                frame.open();
                frame.write(contents);
                frame.close();
                $('#printframe')[0].contentWindow.print();
                return false;
  });
  
});

Answer (score 1):

The print function does not take a screenshot and print that out.  If you wish to be able to print the item in your modal window then you will want to use a [`print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Printing) CSS stylesheet and designate the visibility as `display:block;` or `visibility:visible;` for the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Whatever you want to print wrap it in a div tag with the id "printme"(or whatever you prefer) as you see below.

```
#printme { display: none; }

@media print
{

    #printme { display: block; }
}
</style>
```

```
<div id="printme">
   your image goes here
</div>
```