# How to create a print dialog that displays the current web page's screenshot

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I just want to know if there's easy way to create a print dialog for WordPress that outputs on the print dialogue box the actual view of a webpage. P perhaps a full page screenshot might work as long as it has the full page's height.

I tried [WP-Screenshot](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-screenshot/) plugin on [this page](http://metlifecare.wpengine.com/print). The plugin outputs a screenshot that can be printed out by adding a print dialogue plugin. However, the the height of the image produced by WP-Screenshot can't be dynamic so I guess I need to find another solution.

I can't find a plugin that has the functionality to print the current webpage with all the styles preserved in the print dialogue. So I'm thinking that screenshot might work.

Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to simply call Print dialog? This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603465/using-jquery-to-open-a-popup-window-and-print

Comment: @janek2012, yup, thanks for the headsup it might be helpful on this kind of functionality. However, I need also a screenshot functionality that takes a specific width but will get the full height of the page and display will be displayed as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For printing the page and getting print dialog you can simply use `window.print()`

For better understanding please visit [window.print()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp)

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, this is just a portion of what I need since I still need the functionality to take a screenshot. As you can see, http://metlifecare.wpengine.com/print don't have the full screenshot to print the full page. The bottom part of the screenshot was cut off. 
But thanks anyway.